# Can't acces to syspreped VM

Tags: windows, powershell, hyper-v, windows-server-2016, sysprep

I'm trying to automate things with Windows Server 2016.
Now I can't acces a `sysprep`ed VM via [PowerShell Direct](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/virtualization/2015/05/14/powershell-direct-running-powershell-inside-a-virtual-machine-from-the-hyper-v-host/) because you have to set password for the Administrator account. How can I access this server?

```
PS> icm -VMName S2D1 { ipconfig }
cmdlet Invoke-Command at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
The credential is invalid.
    + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (S2D1:String) [], PSDirectException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PSSessionStateBroken
```

Comment: Are you asking how to pass credentials? AFAICS `Invoke-Command -VMName S2D1 -Scriptblock {...} -Credential (Get-Credential)` should do that.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers but the problem i have not a password and there is not because is sysprepred

Comment: So your question is how to create a credential object with an empty password?

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers this not an ampty password is NO SET the solution is to run script or somethink lik that after sysprepd

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/1949582-setting-up-sysprep-to-run-script-after-logon

Comment: So, again, what is your question?

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers  my problem was that i can't acces to fresh VM because no password  is set and the solution it is to create an answer file using the Windows SIM (System Image Manager)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to create an answer file using the Windows SIM (System Image Manager) which is part of the Windows 10 [ADK](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/windows-assessment-deployment-kit#winADK)
I have to place the answer file inside of the VHDX by mounting it in Windows 10 and then placing the unattend.xml file in the path C:\Windows\Panther

source : [http://www.altaro.com](http://www.altaro.com/hyper-v/powershell-script-deploy-vms-configure-guest-os-one-go/)